# Changing the user role in the jwt token

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

My problem is when the user login and I send a token that includes the roles of that user and then increase or decrease the role of the user. Access is not applied until the token expires and a new token is created.How can I make the previous token invalid when the user's role changes, or if you have a better solution, please help

```
public class JWTAuthorizationManager
{
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;         

    public JWTAuthorizationManager(UserManager<User> _userManager)
    {
        this._userManager = _userManager;
    }
    public async Task<JwtFeildsDto> Authenticate(string UserName, string PasswordHash)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(UserName);
            //پیدا کردن همه نقش های کاربر


        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        //ایجاد تاریخ انقضای توکن
        var tokenExpireTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddHours(Constansts.JWT_TOKEN_EXPIRE_TIME);
        //ایجاد متغیر از کلاس مشخص شده برای ایجاد توکن و اطلاعات همراه آن
        var jwtSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        //ایجاد آرایه ای از بایت ها به عنوان کلید توکن
        var tokenKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Constansts.JWT_SECURITY_KEY_FOR_TOKEN);
        //از این کلاس برای نگهداری ویژگیها و اطلاعات درون توکن استفاده می شود.
        var List = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim("username", UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.PrimaryGroupSid,"User Group 01")

            };

        foreach (var item in roles)
        {
            List.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, item));

        }
        var securityTokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {

            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(List),

            Expires = tokenExpireTimeStamp,

            //امضا یا اعتبارنامه یا مجوز ورود
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(tokenKey),SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };



        var securityToken = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.CreateToken(securityTokenDescriptor);
        var token = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);
 

            return new JwtFeildsDto
            {
                token = token,
                user_name = UserName,
                expire_time = (int)tokenExpireTimeStamp.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds

            };

    }
```

---

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromForm] String userName, String password,bool remmberMe)
    {


            var result = await _loginService.UserLogin(userName, password,remmberMe);

            if (result == true)
            {
                var jwtAuthorizationManager = new JWTAuthorizationManager(_userManager);
                var loginResult = await jwtAuthorizationManager.Authenticate(userName, password);
                return Ok(loginResult);
            }


                return Unauthorized(MessageLib.Message.unaAuthorized);
    }
```

Comment: in your client set update access token claim on refresh option set as true

Comment: or also you clear persitGrant store data to particular user so the token is invalid to user

Comment: Please write this as an answer with my codes. Thank you very much

Comment: you have only generated and login method 
Share your role update code as well

Comment: this is for clients table column updateaccesstokenclaimonrefresh set true

Answer (score 0):

General solution is refresh token.
When user login, he get access token & refresh token.

The access token with user principals exipred in a shorter time such as 1 day. This prevents the old principals(roles) keeps being effective. When access token expired, you can get a new access token just using the refresh token. thus you don't have to login again to get access token, the refresh token authenticate for you.

refresh token has longer expire time such as months, but it doesn't contain any information of user principals(roles). It is just used for getting new access token which contains user principals(roles).
Refresh token is simply generated , just a random code:

```
        private static string GenerateRefreshToken()
        {
            var randomNumber = new byte[64];
            using var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
            rng.GetBytes(randomNumber);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(randomNumber);
        }
```

For how refresh token work,you can try this tutorial with codes can be downloaded.  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-authentication-with-refresh-tokens-in-net-6-0/